# Which NetLogo NW-Extension to use?

Tags: netlogo

Just wondering which NW version to use for netlogo 5.0.5.  Version 0.02 (beta) says it has the snapshot and the new version has in-context (which I need).  However, the download link is to version 0.02.  can someone point in the right direction and advise which version to use with netlogo 5.05.

regards

Simon

Comment: "the download link is to version 0.02" — where? is there something that should have been updated but hasn't been?

Comment: It was out of date on https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions. Now updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page should always have the latest releases:
https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension/releases

**Edit**: as of [NetLogo 5.1](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/5.1.0/), the NW extension is bundled with NetLogo, so there should be no need to download it separately.